# Using php to UPDATE my sql for a review page

Tags: php, sql

So this should be my last question for this entire project. I've made the employee timecard pages. Works great. I'm trying to make them a review/change page per timecard. Basically the initial review page pulls up the timecards they've submitted. They select Review. It carries the ID number to a review page, and I call upon the ID number to display all the info from that timecard into the new timecard html/php form. (Basically its the exact same form they used to submit, however I've echo'd the values as the option already)

When I do update though it's not only carrying over the echo'd value. It's only Updating any changes they make, and in fact deleting everything else. Below is a snippit of just one drop-down list (all over non drop-down's update fine. This is just for drop down lists where the data is contained in the DB.

```
 <select name="starttime" id="input_6" style="width:150px">
            <option value="" selected><?php echo $stime ?></option>
          <?php

                $result = mysql_query("SELECT time FROM selTime ORDER BY id");

                 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                 echo "<option value=\"" . $row['time'] . "\">" . $row['time'] . "                                              </option>";

                }

             ?>
      </select>
```

So what happens with this code. Is when they open the review page They would see their start time as they submitted it. If they leave it alone, and not change anything and push submit after changing something else. The starttime actually UPDATES as blank. If they change the starttime to a value it DOES submit the change. Is there something in this code that I can change that will submit the echo'd value, instead of just displaying it?

Comment: The update code works fine. I didn't think I needed to post it. And there are over 50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is with this line of code:

```
<option value="" selected><?php echo $stime ?></option>
```

Although you set it as "selected" the selected element has the value of "" (empty). Try changing it to:

```
<option value="<?php echo $stime; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $stime; ?></option>
```

Answer (score 0):

If they dont change this select list item, and submit the page directly, the selected item is the first one with the value="", so this will update in the database with blank ( null).

You need to give your fist item a value of date time now. This code here:

```
 <option value="DATETINMENOW" selected><?php echo $stime ?></option>
```

Comment: Is there a way to change my code to echo the $stime as first value?

Comment: just found : $date = date( "d/m/Y", time() ); Use this variable and concatenate it in your first option

Comment: Sorry to confuse you with the starttime. MOST of the other drop down lists are for things like JOBSITE, where they pull down and select the jobsite they were at Option1=This customer Option2=That customer. The starttime was just the first dropdown on my list. And they select what time they started there day from a list. We use lists on the time, just so that the format always stays the same, and they don't have to type anything really.